# EE3 Grid - Row count doesn't change when you rearrange

Tags: grid

I've uploaded images to each row and rearranged them afterwards. Then in my EE code I want to show row_id="1" but it's not taking the rearrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try offset or > in your conditional

```
{project_photos}
    {if project_photos:count == 1} 
        View Photos
    {/if}
{/project_photos}
```

(realize this will only show if there is one, and only one, photo, do you mean >= 1?)

```
{project_photos offset="1" OR > 1} {/project_photos}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rearrangement will change the ORDER ID of Grid not ROW ID. If you want to do some code on first row of GRID, You can try something like this:

```
{grid}
    {if grid:count == 1}
        {!-- My code --}
    {/if}
{/grid}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply!

I'm using a Lightbox and want to hide the first image from the the full gallery but it still shows the first photo from the gallery.

```
{project_photos}
{if project_photos:count == 1}
<a class="button" href="{project_photos:photo:crop}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="{project_photos:caption}">View Photos</a>
{/if}
{/project_photos}

{project_photos row_id="not 1"}
<a href="{project_photos:photo:crop}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="{project_photos:caption}"></a>
{/project_photos}
```